# Undefined function or variable 'BufferedImageLuminanceSource'

Tags: java, matlab, qr-code, zxing, external-dependencies

I recently used `decode_qr` from [this FEX submission](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29239-qr-code-encode-and-decode) to decode my QR code. It ran quite well one or two weeks ago, but today it generate an error for me:

```
Undefined function or variable 'BufferedImageLuminanceSource'
Error in decode_qr (line 34);
source = BufferedImageLuminanceSource(jig);
```

I just checked the [zxing repository](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and found that some files were updated several days ago. So I guess the path of some imported file from the package has been changed.

Here is the importing code from the `decode_qr` function:

```matlab
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.*;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.*;
import com.google.zxing.*;
import com.google.zxing.common.*;
import com.google.zxing.Result.*;
```

How can I get it to work again? Do I need to change the import paths?

Comment: Even if the repository got updated, unless you downloaded a new version manually, there shouldn't have been any effect on your local environment. Did you change anything else during these past 2 weeks, like updating your MATLAB version? It seems to me like your local [java classpath](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaclasspath.html) was reset.

Comment: @Dev-iL No. I didn't do anything to my Matlab. But you remind me one thing: I can't have my new adds-on toolbox in my previous adds-on folder anymore since yesterday. So I guess my default adds-on folder is changed, though I don't know why and how. I never changed it myself. So how should I change it back?

Comment: But if its the problem of my java classpath, then I can fix this problem by uninstall the package and re-install it again, right? But re-install doesn't help at all.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem now. If I cannot, I'll provide the steps I took to make it work. For now, you should check both your static and dynamic java classpaths in MATLAB to see if any of them points to the zxing `.jar` files.

Comment: I can't find any path in my static java path pointing to zxing files, and my dynamic java path is empty....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it to work (Win 10 x64, R2017b, ZXing 3.3.1):

1. Downloaded the latest prebuilt `.jar` artifacts from [Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~com.google.zxing):

   - [core](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~com.google.zxing~core~~~~kw,versionexpand%20).
   - [javase](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~com.google.zxing~javase~~~~kw,versionexpand%20).
2. Added the files to my dynamic java classpath using [`javaaddpath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaaddpath.html):

   ```matlab
   javaaddpath('G:\core-3.3.1.jar');
   javaaddpath('G:\javase-3.3.1.jar');
   % Verify using: javaclasspath('-dynamic');
   ```

   [Note](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaaddpath.html#btppr5r-2):

   > *To add folders to the static path, which MATLAB loads at startup, create a `javaclasspath.txt` file, as described in [Static Path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/static-path.html)*.
3. Generated some example QR code using [unitag.io](https://www.unitag.io/qrcode):
   [image: Sample QR]
4. Tried to decode it using Lior Shapira's [`decode_qr`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29239-qr-code-encode-and-decode?focused=5170461&tab=function):

   ```
   >> out = decode_qr(qr)
   out =

       'https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il'
   ```

---

Full code:

```matlab
function out = q47223578()

javaaddpath('G:\core-3.3.1.jar');
javaaddpath('G:\javase-3.3.1.jar');
% Verify using: javaclasspath('-dynamic');

qr = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA4eP.png');

out = decode_qr(qr);
```